# INET3.6.6 with OMNET 5.5.1/EEE802.1Q VLAN tagging

Tags: c++11, omnet++, inet, vlan

is IEEE802.1Q VLAN tagging supporting in INET 3.6.6? if not is there any example that could help me to implement it ??

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for IEEE802.1Q in INET 3.6.6.

As for implementing, you can take a look how it is implemented INET 4.x or simply just use INET 4.2 or later.

If for some reason you have to stick with INET 3.x, the Core4INET project also had some implementations for VLAN tagging, however I do not recommend taking this approach.